# Assignment of the attribute value does not work

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to merge two FlowFile by filename attribute. The `UpdateAttribute` contains `filename` -> `${UUID()}`. Then `EvaluateJsonPath` has `filname` -> `$.filename`. However finally I get two FlowFiles with different `filename` attributes that cannot be merged:

- Output of`EvaluateJsonPath`: the value of `filename` is an empty string
- Output of `QueryElasticsearchHttp`: the value of `filename` is `1`.

How to make these two outputs to have the pair of same values of `filename`?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample of the content being passed to EvaluateJsonPath?  Can you share what your ExecuteScript is doing? The actual script would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge by filename just put an UpdateAttribute right before MergeContent and set filename to a constant value like 'myfielname'.

There seems to be no reason for the UpdateAttribute at the beginning of the flow, since you are going to overwrite filename in the EvaluateJsonPath processor, plus I think all flow files should already have filename set to the flow file's uuid, unless it came from a GetFile which set the filename from the file on disk.